# Chunked encoded messages in Python Requests Library

Tags: python, http, python-requests, generator, chunked-encoding

I am currently developing a program in Python 3 that shall send a chunked encoded message in a POST Request to an arbitrary  URL.  As described in the docs of the library Requests (see "**chunked-encoded requests**" under https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/user/advanced/), one can use a Generator to specify a chunked encoded message. At the moment, I can not verify whether my Generator gets the job done, because everytime i try to print out the message body of the request with

```python
print(response.request.body)
```

i get the following:

```python
<generator object generator at 0x03FEB530>
```

For example, I want to send the following message in a request. (with C**ontent-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded)**

```python
x=FOO
```

In a chunked encoded message, the message body shall look like this:

```python
5\r\n
x=FOO\r\n
0\r\n
\r\n
```

In a whole request, it should look like this:

```python
POST / HTTP/1.1
Host: example.com
Transfer-Encoding: chunked

5
x=FOO
0
```

I wrote my own Generator and wanted to ask whether this is the correct way of doing it. You can see it in the code snippet below.

```python
def generator():
    var1 = "5\r\n"
    var2= "x=FOO\r\n"
    var3= "0\r\n\r\n"
    x = var1.encode('utf8')
    y = var2.encode('utf8')
    z = var3.encode('utf8')
    yield x
    yield y
    yield z

url = 'https://example.com'
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:71.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/71.0',
           'Connection': 'keep-alive', 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
           'Transfer-Encoding': 'chunked'}
response = requests.post(url=url, data=generator(), headers=headers)
```

Disclaimer: I do not want my generator to automatically generate the chunked encoding of a message, I want to send a request with a specific chunked encoded message like shown above.

Comment: Can you do `print(list(response.request.body))` to turn your generator into a list?

Comment: I then receive two square brackets ( **[ ]** ) as an output in my program.